# Understanding Biblatex's abbreviations

Tags: biblatex

One of my students has asked me the following question, which I have no idea how to answer.

In the following example, why does one entry contain the abbreviation **comm.** while the other contains the abbreviation **comment.**. I'm assuming that both are intended to be abbreviations for 'commentary', but I do not know why Biblatex distinguishes the two cases. (The distinction is clearly deliberate - see below.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{ch-with-comm,
  author        =   {Author, A. N.},
  title         =   {Arduous Anti-Adventures},
  pages         =   {3--4},
  editor        =   {Cracks, Wise and Alec, Smart},
  commentator   =   {Cracks, Wise and Alec, Smart},
  booktitle    =   {Positive Pitfalls},
  publisher     =   {BRU},
  address       =   {Universe},
  year          =   2009}
@incollection{chap-with-comm,
  author        =   {Author, A. N. Other},
  title         =   {Bonkers Boggling Bathrobes},
  pages         =   {39--47},
  editor        =   {Cracks, Wise and Alec, Smart},
  commentator   =   {Cracks, Wise},
  booktitle    =   {Positive Pitfalls},
  publisher     =   {BRU},
  address       =   {Universe},
  year          =   2009}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\Autocite{ch-with-comm,chap-with-comm}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: comm, comment and commentary by commentator(s)]

In `english.lbx`, we have

```
  withcommentator  = {{with a commentary by}{with a comment\adddot\ by}},
```

but this is the only place in which the abbreviation is `comment\adddot` rather than `comm\adddot`.

Looking at the way Biblatex handles string definitions, I must admit that it seems to be a recipe for inconsistency, since nothing is *reused*. That is, I would have expected a *single* definition for, say, each of `\commentary@full` and `\commentary@abbrv`, which would then be reused when defining subsequent strings requiring the same word. This would make it easy for users to override a default, if desired, and help to ensure consistency and ease of maintenance. But, instead, the same basic definition is basically repeated over and over, will all the concomitant room for error.

But, very clearly, Biblatex is a thoroughly considered and carefully designed package. So I find it difficult to believe that there is no reason for either the system, in general, or the apparent discrepancy, in particular.

Could somebody enlighten us?

## EDIT

Note that, in other cases, `comm\adddot` is used regardless of whether the long form is `commented` or `commentary`. For example,

```
translatorscoaf  = {{translation, commentary\finalandcomma\ and afterword}%
                  {trans., comm\adddot\finalandcomma\ and afterw\adddot}}
```

where 'commentary' is abbreviated as `comm\adddot`, and

```
byeditorco       = {{edited and commented by}%
                  {ed\adddotspace and comm\adddot\ by}},
```

where 'commented' is abbreviated by `comm\adddot`.

Comment: In the first case it is “edited and commented by”, in the second case it's “with a commentary by”.

Comment: @egreg But in other cases where the long form has 'commentary', the abbreviation used is `comm\adddot`. For example, `translatorscoaf  = {{translation, commentary\finalandcomma\ and afterword}%
                      {trans., comm\adddot\finalandcomma\ and afterw\adddot}}`. That's just one example.

Comment: @egreg And similarly for 'commented'. For example, `byeditorco       = {{edited and commented by}%
                      {ed\adddotspace and comm\adddot\ by}},`. ('Commented' sounds most bizarre to me regardless, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: I can't find any earlier version than `biblatex` 1.0 from `2010/11/19`. At that point the behaviour you describe was already present. I assume this inconsistency was an oversight. We unfortunately can't ask Philipp Lehman about it. If this discrepancy bothers you, I think PLK would not mind a change of the translations (I don't think he would mind a thorough examination of the strings either).

Comment: BTW: The acknowledgement section of the docs make me thing Philipp Lehman did the English translations himself, but I think he is/was a German native speaker, so some rough edges are to be expected.

Comment: @moewe I never thought about it before, but I guess it bothers me now it has been pointed out. And one thing I emphasise to students is consistency of formatting, so it is not good if I can't justify apparent discrepancies. (Not to mention the errors I introduced all of my own, but I know what to do about those!) Do you think PLK would be interested in a revised version of the English translation? 'Commented by' really seems wrong to me because a commentary is not the same as comments.

Comment: I'm quite sure he would. And if not he then at least I would be very grateful. The 'commented by' works reasonably well in German if translated literally, that might explain it. Even more reason to have a native speaker investigate the strings (the less often used ones, especially) properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `commentator` field was introduced in version 0.5 of `biblatex`. I could obtain version 0.8, and in that version the commentator/commentary-related strings were already as they are today.

Unfortunately, we can't ask Philipp Lehmann why things are the way they are. I think it is fair to assume that this was an oversight. Since the string is among the more rarely used, I think it is not at all unlikely that an inconsistency like this remained undetected for quite some time.

Either PL wanted to abbreviate 'commentator' and 'commentary' differently, and that was forgotten about when the combined bibstrings were written; or he didn't mean to do so and the `comment\adddot` was an oversight and not intentional.

There are a few other inconsistencies in `english.lbx` with respect to the punctuation commands used. I assume they arose because the file grew organically and was not written in one go.

It is true that the `.lbx`s in their current form feature quite bit of redundancy, especially when it comes to the 'combined' bibstrings. Introducing another layer of macros would make things more complicated and was probably not seen as necessary when things started out. When things grow it is not always possible to foresee what is going to be needed.

Comment: Presumably, it is possible to use macros in the definitions, though, as `\adddot` etc. are used here, so it could be done if it makes sense now ....

Comment: @cfr Absolutely, it is. The use of macros for recurring strings is just not practice at the moment and would ideally be supported by a proper interface. This would turn the translations into a two-pass structure with interdependencies, translations will look more daunting. I admit that the current redundant situation is not ideal, but I'm not sure if using macros is going to make things better.

Comment: @cfr One thing occurred to me: Even at the moment there is no problem 'stacking' bibstrings, so in theory `editorco = {\bibstring{editor} \bibstring{and} \bibstring{commentator}},` is possible. In case one needs a string that is not already defined it is easy to define a new one from within the `.lbx`.